# Splatting arguments for external program

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a powershell script that runs CMake. Here is my sample code (splatting `CMAKE_OPTIONS` at the end):

```
$CMAKE_OPTIONS = @{
  "DBUILD_opencv_java:BOOL" = "OFF"
  "DBUILD_opencv_python:BOOL" = "OFF"
  "DBUILD_opencv_python2:BOOL" = "OFF"
  "DBUILD_opencv_python3:BOOL" = "OFF"
  "DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL" = "OFF"
  "DBUILD_PERF_TESTS:BOOL" = "OFF"
  "DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL" = "OFF"
  "DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL" = "OFF"
  "DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB:BOOL" = "ON"
}
# ... add something from user input
cmake -G $CMAKE_CONFIG_GENERATOR -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=$myRepo/opencv_contrib/modules -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$myRepo/install/$REPO_SOURCE $myRepo/$REPO_SOURCE @CMAKE_OPTIONS
```

But I get an error:

> Parse error in command line argument: -DBUILD_opencv_python:BOOL:OFF
>   Should be: VAR:type=value
>   CMake Error: No cmake script provided.
>   CMake Error: Problem processing arguments. Aborting.

It seems that instead of writing arguments `foo = bar` it does `foo:bar`.
How to splat arguments correctly when calling external program? Or do I have to use an old approach with string concatenation and `&cmake -p "myargs" $CMAKE_OPTIONS_STRING`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For external programs use an array, not a hashtable:

```
$CMAKE_OPTIONS = @(
  "-DBUILD_opencv_java:BOOL=OFF",
  "-DBUILD_opencv_python:BOOL=OFF",
  "-DBUILD_opencv_python2:BOOL=OFF",
  "-DBUILD_opencv_python3:BOOL=OFF",
  "-DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF",
  "-DBUILD_PERF_TESTS:BOOL=OFF",
  "-DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF",
  "-DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF",
  "-DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB:BOOL=ON"
)

cmake ... @CMAKE_OPTIONS
```

Comment: Is it possible to write to host command which exactly get executed? I mean in this example it should be `cmake -DBUILD_opencv_java:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_python:BOOL=OFF ...` ? I'd like to have some logging to make sure it's called properly.

Comment: `echo "cmake ... $CMAKE_OPTIONS"`

Comment: It's sad that it cannot be automatically done, because as any copy-paste this one tends to actually do not what it claims since it firstly changed...

Comment: Well, there's always [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-3.0).